# Looking for HTTPS (single-target) relay proxy

Tags: http, proxy, centos-7

At $DAYJOB, we produce several devices (1), both embedded Linux devices and regular servers running specialized software on Red Hat or CentOS Linux. These devices monitor specialized data networks, but also have access to a management network. The data network normally, and the management network often, do not have access the Internet.

We also have a management console software (2), which runs on Red Hat or CentOS Linux, which has access to the management network and the Internet.

I am trying to get the (1) devices to authenticate themselves over the Internet towards a machine that we control over HTTPS (3). Since they most often do not have access to the Internet directly, I want set up a relay proxy server on (2) that they can use to connect to our server.

The relay proxy server on (2) will only ever connect over HTTPS to a single host (single DNS entry), and should reject any other connection attempts. The software on (1) will

I have tried looking for any existing software that would let me do this, so that I would not have to implement it all myself. The (1) devices will validate that the data they get from the (3) host is correct using certificates, and the connection between the (1) devices and the (2) proxy host is on a private network, so it is fine if that part of the connection is plain HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [tinyproxy](https://tinyproxy.github.io/) with a filtering setup to only allow a single host name. I am unable to get it to accept `CONNECT` requests only, so it will proxy HTTP as well to the target host name, but that is good enough for me.